# Implementing Flask-login with neo4j

Tags: flask, neo4j, py2neo

I'm trying to implement Flask-login with neo4j. Trying to implement using this [Flask Login Documentation](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

I have added the four method to the user class

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True 

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    def find(self):
        user = graph.find_one("User", "username", self.username)
        return user
```

When I try to call login_user(user) I get error

```
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if not User(username).verify_password(password):
            flash('Invalid login.')
        else:
            session['username'] = username
            flash('Logged in.')

            user = User(username).find()
            login_user(user)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html')
```

I get this error

> File "/../auth/view.py", line 134, in login 
>       login_user(user) 
>   File "/../lib/python3.4/site-packages/flask_login.py", line 709, in login_user
>       if not force and not user.is_active: 
>   AttributeError: 'Node' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Also, I'm not sure of is how to define load user callback function.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.get(user_id)
```

I cannot find any documentation that covers this topic. Can somebody help to get this to work or point to the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The `find_one` method returns a `Node`. You presumably want to return the `username` property of that `Node` rather than the whole entity. So you'll need something like:

```
def find(self):
    user = graph.find_one("User", "username", self.username)
    # TODO: handle the case where user is None (user not found)
    return user["username"]
```

Comment: Still doesn't solve the issue. Now, I get this error - AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_active'.  I guess there is a difference how User class is represented in other DBs compared to Neo4j. Looking at definition of login_user, it says "Logs a user in. You should pass the actual user object to this". And it tried to access user property "user.is_active".  Is it possible to return object representation of Node?. For e.g mongoDb "find_one" method return object representation of document